# Rails: destroying multiple user-to-user associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, callback, associations

I have a model called `Block` that has a `blocker_id` (a user_id) and a `blocked_user_id` field (also a user_id). The `Block` model lets one user block another. When one user blocks another, I want it to destroy the `Relationship` between them using a `before_save` method for the `Block` class. The `Relationship` table has a `follower_id` and a `followed_id`.

This is where things get tricky. I know I could achieve this goal by using multiple `return if Relationship.xyz.nil?` statements and then using multiple `Relationship.find_by(follower_id:  , followed_id:  ).destroy` statements, but this gets to be way over complicated because each `blocker` and `blocked_user` could be either the `follower` and `followed` id, both, or neither. Is there any easier way to do this?

Here's my models for reference: (also the `Block` class has a `blocked_post` field, which I'm having no trouble with)

```
class Block < ActiveRecord::Base

validates :blocker_id, presence: true
validates :blocked_user_id, uniqueness: {scope: :blocker_id}, allow_nil: true
validates :blocked_post_id, uniqueness: {scope: :blocker_id}, allow_nil: true 
validate  :blocked_user_or_post
after_validation :validate_block
before_save :destroy_blocked_relationships


belongs_to(
    :blocker,
    class_name: "User"
    )

has_one(
    :blocked_user,
    class_name: "User"
    )

has_one(
    :blocked_post,
    class_name: "Post"
    )

private

def blocked_user_or_post
  blocked_user_id.blank? ^ blocked_post_id.blank?
end


def validate_block
  if blocked_user_id.present?
    !(blocker_id == blocked_user_id)
  elsif blocked_post_id.present?
    blocked_post = Post.find_by(id: self.blocked_post_id).user_id
    !(blocker_id == blocked_post)
  else
    false
  end
end

def destroy_blocked_relationships
  #my over-complex code was here
end

end
```

relationship.rb:

```
class Relationship < ActiveRecord::Base


validates :follower_id, :followed_id, presence: {message: 'Need an eligible follower and followee id'}
validates :followed_id, uniqueness: { scope: :follower_id}


belongs_to(
   :follower, 
   class_name: "User"
   )

belongs_to(
   :followed, 
   class_name: "User"
   )
end
```

If there is any way to do this that doesn't require massive amounts of code, I'd really like to know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: in this line, did you mean to name the variable something else? `blocked_post = Post.find_by(id: self.blocked_post_id).user_id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure of your exact use case, but my thoughts about a system where people can follow each other, it seems that the blocker would always be the person being followed.  If this is the case, here's an implementation:

```
def destroy_blocked_relationships
  Relationship.where(follower_id:blocked_user_id, followed_id:blocker_id).destroy_all
  true
end
```

If it makes sense to also block someone from being being followed, you could add this:

```
Relationship.where(follower_id:blocker_id, followed_id:blocked_user_id).destory_all
```

Here it is all together, and stopping the save of the Block if there are no relationships:

```
before_save :destroy_blocked_relationships

def destroy_blocked_relationships
  relationships = Relationship.where("(follower_id = ? AND followed_id = ?) OR (followed_id = ? AND follower_id = ? )", blocked_user_id, blocker_id, blocked_user_id, blocker_id)
  relationships.destroy_all
  relationships.present?  # Omit this line if the save should continue regardless
end
```

Comment: I don't think this will destroy the relationships where the blocker is the follower and the blocked_user is the followed, will it?

Comment: Okay, now the only problem is that I need to check if these are if .nil? before I attempt to delete them, because this is a validation and these two users will most likely not have any kind of relationship at all. When you add an if relationship.xyz.nil? twice, then I'm right back to where I started

Comment: If there is no relationship, the result of Relationship.where(...) will be an empty set, which will not destroy anything.

Comment: Nope, like I said, it runs as a callback method, so it will return false if there is no relationship and wont save a user-user block, and wont save a user-post block because that fails too. Even when the callback is after_save

Comment: Oh yeah - as it's in an ActiveRecord callback, you need to return true if you want it to continue saving.  I'll add another example in case you don't want to save if there are no Relationships.

Comment: @user3181113 My Pleasure.  Please accept this answer.

Comment: Totally forgot! I apologize. I was very tired last night.

Answer (score 0):

here is my understanding:

- a Block is a relationship between two users, OR between a User and a Post
- when a Block is created between user A and Post X, an implicit block is also created between User A and User B, where User B is Post X's author

Consider making two models, BlockedPost and BlockedUser. Then, make two `#make` methods. This makes all the related logic easier to reason about.

```
# class BlockedPost
def make(user, post)
  transaction do
    create!(user: user, post: post)
    BlockedUser.make(user, post.author)
  end
end

# class BlockedUser
def make(user, blocked_user)
  transaction do
    create!(user: user, blocked_user: blocked_user)
    Relationship.where(follower: user, following: blocked_user).destroy_all
    Relationship.where(follower: blocked_user, following: user).destroy_all
  end
end
```